# If I give row_cache_size_in_mb =5Gb in cassandra.yaml file, does cassandra reserves 5GB from Heap Memory?

Tags: cassandra, installation, heap-memory, cassandra-2.0

I am running my cassandra cluster having memory  32 GB on each node,
And row cache capacity (row_cache_size_in_mb) 5GB,
Just want to know, does 5gb memory ram is reserved for row caching from my heap??

Answer (score 3):

It will let it grow to that size over time. Can use `nodetool info` to see the current size and limit and `nodetool setcachecapacity` to change it at runtime. Note that its kinda an estimate though and heap can grow a bit larger. I would be sure to test that the row_cache is actually improving things though since in a lot of cases having no row cache can be faster.

Comment: just want to know , is cassandra uses row-cache capacity from the heap given to cassandra? i.e. if have given 5gb to row_cache and Max_heap size32gb , is cassandra uses 5gb from 32 gb heap?

Comment: It depends on versions and settings. In 3.0+ by default `row_cache_class_name` is set to `org.apache.cassandra.cache.OHCProvider` which is an off heap cache from: https://github.com/snazy/ohc. Before that or if it is set to `org.apache.cassandra.cache.SerializingCacheProvider` it will be on heap.